# python apscheduler not consistent

Tags: python, scheduler, blocking, web.py, apscheduler

I'm running a scheduler using *python* **apscheduler** inside *web.py* framework.
The function **runserver** is supposed to run everyday at 9 a.m but it is inconsistent.
It runs most days but skips a day once in a while.

Code:

```
import web
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler #Blocking Scheduler

#URLs
urls = (
    '/startscheduler/','index',
    )

Nightlysched = BlockingScheduler()

@Nightlysched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=9)
def runserver():
    print 2+2 #doing some calculations here

#Main function to run the cron JOB
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Nightlysched.start() #stating the job
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

What is the correct way to configure the scheduler to run every day at 9.a.m?

Comment: I can't understand how this code works at all. Nightlysched.start() will block and not let your web app run. That said, the configuration is correct. Please enable debug logging (set loglevel of "apscheduler" to DEBUG) to figure out what's going on.

Comment: After the scheduler starts (Nightlysched.start()) it run the web app as expected.  Can you please tell me how to set loglevel of apscheduler? I tried few things but it didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

APScheduler has a *grace period* during which jobs are allowed to run. If for some reason the scheduler is busy and/or the load of the host is too high, APScheduler might fail to start the job in time.

In this cases, the job will be discarded if it could not be started during the grace time (an explanatory message will be logged if you have initialized Python logging).

Depending on the actual root cause:

- If the scheduler failed to schedule the job in time, you can use `misfire_grace_time=None` to tell APScheduler to schedule the job as soon as it can instead of discarding it.
- By default, only one instance of each job is allowed to be run at the same time. Make sure the previous run has finished. It is possible to set the maximum number of instances for a particular job that the scheduler will let run concurrently, by using the `max_instances` keyword argument when adding the job. In this case you also may need to use `coalesce=False`. Do this only if the job takes longer than 24 hours (in your case) and you accept that two instances of your job could be running simultaneously.
- If there were too many jobs running, but the machine load wasn't too high, it means you have more jobs than what you can run concurrently. You can try increasing the size of the thread pool that APScheduler *executor* is using to run jobs (this depends on your setup, check: http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html).

In summary, I'd first try with `misfire_grace_period`:

```
@Nightlysched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=9, misfire_grace_time=None)
```

As a note, though, as @Alex mentioned I don't grasp why your code works, because the call to `Nightlysched.start()` should be blocking and preventing your web application from running. I guess this is pasted code and doesn't really represent what you are running. To me, it looks like you should instead be using a non-blocking scheduler like BackgroundScheduler.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation jjmontes. I will try this out. Also I was also thinking that Background scheduler is a better option but was unable to schedule a job with background scheduler everyday at 9. All the examples I could find were interval configured, something like scheduler.add_job(runfunction, 'interval', minutes=15) . Can you tell me how to convert the interval to a daily hour cron?

Comment: Try `scheduler.add_job(your_function, trigger='cron', hour=9, misfire_grace_time=None)`. The trigger argument can be "date", "interval" or "cron", or you could even implement your own trigger class (I never needed to do this ;)).

Comment: Also, have a look at the [source code and doc of `add_job`](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/src/a6545cf29831bb6d8f055aeb2fa9d5204e9bd192/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#base.py-315), I found it quite informative!

Comment: @jjmontes - Thank you very much! Your explanation is very simple n pretty much helpful. I would request Alex to add your explanation in apscheduler doc.(even though its there ;) )

Comment: Wow! Hadn't realized @AlexGronholm was APScheduler author himself! He can surely correct/improve my text, who else better! :D